# Добавление Inline кнопки к Reply клавиатуре telebot

Tags: python, telebot

В `pay`, там где `BTN1` необходимо добавить инлайн-кнопку со ссылкой. но там уже прописана реплай-клавиатура. Каким образом её можно туда добавить? Смотрел в видеоуроках, но там в `pay` создается инлайн-клавиатура, а реплай-клавиатура подтягивается с предыдущего сообщения, т.е. с `buy`. У меня же в `pay` реплай-клавиатура уже с другими кнопками

```
def buy(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row('BTN1', 'BTN2')
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Text', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, pay)

def pay(message):
   if message.text == "BTN1":
        key2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        key2.row('BTN3', 'BTN4')
        msg2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Some Text', reply_markup=key2)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg2, pay1)
    elif message.text == "BTN2":
        ...
```

Comment: почему нельзя отказаться от `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`?

Comment: Да мне проще от инлайн отказаться, указав ссылку в сообщении. Но хотелось бы оформить её отдельной кнопкой

Comment: в чём критичность для вас использовать `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`? в вашем примере эти кнопки не запрашивают контакт, так почему не заменить их на `Inline`?